# how to display the content before exit() in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, exit

I'm using codeigniter. And in one of my admin controller, after a admin was logged in, I wanted to create a switch to check his admin level. If his level is below a certain number, he cannot view a certain page. And instead, a restriction notice page will be loaded and then the page will stop loading.

```
function add_user() {

    $this->set_admin_level(9);
    // stuffs
}

private function set_admin_level($level){

    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_level') < $level ) {

        $this->load->view("admin/restriction");

        exit();
    }

}
```

I tried exit() and die(), but both of them just killed the entire page without displaying anything. I know that I can do this with an if and then redirect method, but I wanted to know if I can do it the previous way.

Comment: Exceptions are useful in this case.  Throw an exception in the set_admin_level() instead of exit() then look for an exception in add_user using try { } catch() { }.  Uncaught exceptions will exit.

Comment: What if you put a message inside die? for example ```die('Not authorized to see this section');``` should display that text. In that case, the problem is that the exit or die statement happens before the template rendering.

Comment: I don't want to display only the error message on a blank page. I want to also load the header and footer template along with it.

Comment: update, I found the solution in here, replacing exit() with die($this->output->get_output());
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618993/php-codeigniter-use-of-exit?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private function set_admin_level($level){

   if ($this->session->userdata('admin_level') < $level ) {

       return $this->load->view("admin/restriction");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

die or exit will stop all PHP processing.

If you don't want an error message on a blank page, you will need a page/view to display the error message.  Then you either redirect the user to that page, or run the page in PHP before exiting, for example using `$this->load->view`.

Either way, you need to create the page or the view first, since you cannot display something by doing nothing.

And before displaying the actual error page, please set the HTTP 403 header to indicate to browsers and search engines that this is an Access Denied error page, not a normal page.